Cannot inject generated grpc client in quarkus extension
I'm writing a Quarkus extension,
I added proto files from envoy proxy to generate classes for grpc client.
I create a AuthService bean and inject Authorization service like this
@ApplicationScoped
public class AuthService {
    @GrpcClient("auth")
    Authorization authorization;
}

In my Processor class, I added AdditionalBeanItem like this
@BuildStep
    public void additionalBeans(BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans,
                                BuildProducer<ReflectiveClassBuildItem> reflectiveClasses) {
        AdditionalBeanBuildItem.Builder builder = AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder().setUnremovable();
        builder.addBeanClass(AuthService.class);
        additionalBeans.produce(builder.build());
    }

When running DevModeTest I got this error:
Build step io.quarkus.grpc.deployment.GrpcClientProcessor#discoverInjectedClients threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: io.envoyproxy.envoy.service.auth.v3.Authorization cannot be injected into com.axon.quarkus.auth.runtime.AuthService#authorization - only Mutiny service interfaces, blocking stubs, reactive stubs based on Mutiny and io.grpc.Channel can be injected via @GrpcClient


I expected that the generated Authorization can be injected into AuthService

Afaik, you answered it yourself on Quarkus GitHub.
